# jQuery and associative form, need help using enable and disable checkbox

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, checkbox

I am in need of help about jQuery and multi-array forms. My form is as follows:

```
<form>
<div class="box" style="border:1px #000 solid">
    <input type="checkbox" name="clause[3][chk]" class="clause_check">
    <input type="text" name="clause[3][number]" class="clause_number numericonly" maxlength="2" size="2" disabled="disabled">
    This is a clause with a text field <input class="clause_input" name="clause[3][field][-_transfer_charges_-]" disabled="disabled" type="text"> to be filled in.
</div>
<div class="box" style="border:1px #000 solid">
    <input type="checkbox" name="clause[2][chk]" class="clause_check">
    <input type="text" name="clause[2][number]" class="clause_number numericonly" maxlength="2" size="2" disabled="disabled">
    This is a clause without a text box to fill.
</div>
<div class="box" style="border:1px #000 solid">
    <input type="checkbox" name="clause[1][chk]" class="clause_check">
    <input type="text" name="clause[1][number]" class="clause_number numericonly" maxlength="2" size="2" disabled="disabled"> 
    Another clause with a 
    <input class="clause_input" name="clause[1][field][-_transfer_charges_-]" disabled="disabled" type="text"> 
    to be filled in.
    <ol type="a">
        <li>This is a sub clause with a <input class="clause_input" name="clause[1][field][-_noc_charges_-]" disabled="disabled" type="text"></li>
        <li>Last sub clause.</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</form>
```

Now, all text box fields are disabled by default. Upon checking the respective checkbox field, all text box fields on the same div will be active and if uncheck, will do the opposite. I am not pretty sure where to start, sorry. I will be using php to process the submitted data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the markup you can try

```
$(function(){

  $(":checkbox").on("change",function(e){

   if($(this).is(":checked"))
      $(this).closest("div.box").find(":input").prop("disabled",false);
  else
     $(this).closest("div.box").find(":input:not(:checkbox)").prop("disabled",true);    
 });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tAkGH/5/)

UPDATE:

if you are generating the form dynamically you can use it like

```
$(document).on("change",":checkbox",function(e){
...
// rest of the code remains the same
```

Comment: checkbox gets disabled after unchecking.. sorry really not a good jquery coder.

Comment: thanks, both answers from 3nigma and dfsq worked well. I noticed that both answers was not working with jquery version 1.6.4.. i just updated my jquery and worked like a charm.

Comment: with the answer you gave, how can I possibly auto-number the clause[n][number] fields upon checking? getting the current auto-number from clause[n][number] if there is already set, and incrementing/decrementing the value?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tAkGH/
And the script:

```
$('body').on('change', '.clause_check', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box').find(':input:not(".clause_check")').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

Comment: sorry, but when i try on my actual form (dynamically created), nothing happens. but markup is likely the same.

Comment: finally got it to worked after I updated my jquery version (1.6.4) to 1.7.1. It seems not to work well with my previous jquery version. Thanks a lot!